# UIButton set as UIBarButtonItem is not disabled when set title on it (Works fine if I use UIImage in UIButton)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIBarButtonItem`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *editBarButton;
```

I simply insert a `UIButton` in `UIBarButtonItem`, with title, font & etc in `viewDidLoad`

```
    editButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    editButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-light" size:18];
    editButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [editButton setTitle:@"Post" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    //[editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_post"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editBarButtonPress:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [editButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 57, 30)];
    self.editBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:editButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editBarButton;
```

Latter I use it in many condition, like in `viewWillAppear` :

```
if (self.chatLogsArray.count)
{
self.editBarButton.enabled = YES;
}
else
{
self.editBarButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

But it is not disable while I use title in Button. But works fine if I set an `UIImage` in `UIButton`. Why is that? And what I am missing?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not disabled"? When I tested your code it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. By saying "disabled" mean is not enable ex: self.editBarButton.enabled = NO; or self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO; 
It works If I comment out this line 
`[editButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_post"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make property and disable `UIButton` instead `UIBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both text and image on `UIButton`, you need to set an image as background:

```
[editButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_post"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```